# How to disable insertion of a period when pressing spacebar?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, kde

For some reason, in certain applications, whenever I press the space bar, a fullstop/period is being inserted after or before the words. It's not happening consistently in all applications, and interestingly enough, it's behaving differently in KDE/Plasma vs. Gnome.

I was able to disable it in Gnome by changing a setting that enabled this feature when pressing CTRL + Space, but in KDE, I can't seem to find anything of the sort, and it's inconsistent.

Nothing useful is showing up in searches on the web, so I'm giving it a shot here.